# What is the main difference between Web 8.5 and Tridion Sites 9.1?

Tags: web8.5, sites-9.1

Am looking for the main difference between both. Can anyone help me in this?

Comment: Here's a good source: https://docs.sdl.com/783502/676235/sdl-tridion-sites-9-1/what%E2%80%99s-new-in-------------sdl-tridion-sites

Comment: Also, 9.5 has been recently released, and has a lot more business-focused improvements you may want to look into.

Answer (score 3):

As you can see @Nuno shared the official release notes of sdl documentation for good source.

In High level listed out main functional and technical features of sites 9.0 and 9.1

**Functional features**

- Pre-defined Regions support
- Usability improvements for Component Presentations
- Blended marketing and product information from SDL Tridion Docs
- Image editing

**Technical Features**

- Shared delivery platform (DXD)
- Shared taxonomies with SDL Tridion Docs
- GraphQL Content API
- Rolling Upgrade Support
- Docker container Support for DXD
- SAML 2.0 support
- Technology agnostic integration framework
- Add-On Management
- Fredhopper replaced to Elastic search for XO

**In SDL Tridion Sites 9.5 released with following features:**

- Experience Space - new UI
- Headless Content Publishing
- Search - SDL Tridion Sites now ships with out-of-the-box support for Elasticsearch-based search for published content
- Semantic Content Models
- Elasticsearch Engine
- OpenID Connect
- Access Management UI

Refer to the SDL Documentation for [release notes](https://docs.sdl.com/783502/676235/sdl-tridion-sites-9-1/what%E2%80%99s-new-in-------------sdl-tridion-sites)

Download What's new in SDL Tridion Sites 9.5 data sheet to [find out more](https://www.sdl.com/products-and-solutions/content-management/sdl-tridion/resources/whats-new-in-tridion-sites/)

I hope it helps